# How to make method do nothing every other time?

Tags: java, android, proximitysensor

I'm trying to making an app that plays a sound only when the proximity sensor is covered, however it plays the sound again when the sensor is uncovered.

How do you make it play the sound only when it is covered and not play any sound when it is uncovered?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


SensorManager sm;
Sensor ProximitySensor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    ProximitySensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    sm.registerListener(proximitySensorEventListener,
            ProximitySensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}



SensorEventListener proximitySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
                call();
        }

    }
};

    private void call() {
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nfcoff);
        ImageView imm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buz);

        if (im.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && imm.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ovnoise);
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });


        } else
            if (im.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && imm.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ovbus);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Look at `event.values[0]` and make decisions based upon the value there. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) for more.

Comment: couldn't find a solution, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Quoting the documentation, `values[0]` is: "Proximity sensor distance measured in centimeters. Note: Some proximity sensors only support a binary near or far measurement. In this case, the sensor should report its maximum range value in the far state and a lesser value in the near state.". So, decide what value of `values[0]` you want to be the dividing line between "covered" and not. Then, use math to determine whether the `values[0]` value that you are getting is above or below that dividing line, and take appropriate action.

Comment: Bear in mind that sensors can be twitchy, so rather than considering a single low value to be a clear sign of "covered", you might want to consider some sort of smoothing algorithm. I don't do a lot of work with sensors, so I don't have a particular algorithm to recommend here -- you'll probably have to do some experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

I added an int count to count how many times the method was called and added an if statement that says the method can only be called if the int is an odd number, making every other time the method was called invalid.

```
static int count = 0;

count++;

if (count % 2 != 0) {}
```